# How to add my output from a "FOR" Loop and sum together

Tags: javascript, html, forms, function, for-loop

I am a beginner, so I want to ask that how to sum my "FOR" loop value from my input form? and the GrandTotal is used to change it "readonly" textbox in my form.

```
let grandTotal = 0;
for(let i = 1; i <= 5; ++i) {
  grandTotal += parseInt(document.getElementById("Total" + i).value);
}
grandTotal = document.getElementById("GrandTotal").value;
```

This is one part of my HTML\

```
<tr id="One">
  <td style="font-family:  papyrus;font-weight: bold;">1</td>
  <td width="20%"><input type="text" id="BookTitle" name="BookTitle" size="30" ></td>
  <td width="17%"><input type="text" id="Author" name="Author" size="10"></td>
  <td width="20%"><select id="Category" name="Category">
    <option value="Please choose the categoty...">Please choose the Category...</option>
    <option value="Business">Business</option>
    <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
    <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
    <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
    </select></td>
  <td width="13%"><input type="text" class="UnitPrice" id="UnitPrice1" name="Unit Price" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" onkeypress="return forNumberOnly(event)"></td>
  <td width="13%"><input type="text" class="Quantity" id="Quantity1" name="Quantity" value="0" min="0" onkeypress="return forNumberOnly(event)"></td>
  <td width="13%"><input type="text" id="Total1" name="Total" value="0.00"  readonly></td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` snippet editor.

Comment: Your current HTML Code would be a help ^^

Comment: Please see my updated answer which does the total across and GrandTotal

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this - I use the selector `[name=Total]` because it makes more sense than `[id^=Total]`

I delegate the change to the tbody:

```js
document.getElementById("tb").addEventListener("change", function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  const parent = tgt.closest("tr");
  const up  = +parent.querySelector(".UnitPrice").value || 0
  const qty = +parent.querySelector(".Quantity").value || 0
  parent.querySelector("[name=Total]").value = (up * qty).toFixed(2);
  
  const grandTotal = [...document.querySelectorAll("[name=Total]")] // all total
    .map(ele => +ele.value) // get each value and convert to number
    .reduce((a, b) => a + b); // sum them
  document.getElementById("GrandTotal").value = grandTotal; // assign to a field
})
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody id="tb">
    <tr id="One">
      <td style="font-family:  papyrus;font-weight: bold;">1</td>
      <td width="20%"><input type="text" id="BookTitle" name="BookTitle" size="30"></td>
      <td width="17%"><input type="text" id="Author" name="Author" size="10"></td>
      <td width="20%">
        <select id="Category" name="Category">
          <option value="Please choose the categoty...">Please choose the Category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td width="13%"><input type="text" class="UnitPrice" id="UnitPrice1" name="Unit Price" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00"></td>
      <td width="13%"><input type="text" class="Quantity" id="Quantity1" name="Quantity" value="0" min="0"></td>
      <td width="13%"><input type="text" id="Total1" name="Total" value="0.00" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="Two">
      <td style="font-family:  papyrus;font-weight: bold;">1</td>
      <td width="20%"><input type="text" id="BookTitle" name="BookTitle" size="30"></td>
      <td width="17%"><input type="text" id="Author" name="Author" size="10"></td>
      <td width="20%">
        <select id="Category" name="Category">
          <option value="Please choose the categoty...">Please choose the Category...</option>
          <option value="Business">Business</option>
          <option value="Fiction">Fiction</option>
          <option value="Mathematics">Mathematics</option>
          <option value="Technology">Technology</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td width="13%"><input type="text" class="UnitPrice" id="UnitPrice2" name="Unit Price" step="0.01" value="0.00" placeholder="0.00" onkeypress="return forNumberOnly(event)"></td>
      <td width="13%"><input type="text" class="Quantity" id="Quantity2" name="Quantity" value="0" min="0" onkeypress="return forNumberOnly(event)"></td>
      <td width="13%"><input type="text" id="Total2" name="Total" value="0.00" readonly></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<input type="text" readonly id="GrandTotal" />
```